# Captured H.264 over RTP Skips ahead after playback

Tags: c#, h.264

I'm really stumped on this one, I've been looking at it now for 2 days and haven't gotten anywhere. I am capturing encoded H.264 packets over RTP using some C# and the information in the file looks solid as far as I can tell.

Essentially I get my SPS which is telling me High profile, the resolution is 1280x720. Then I get my PPS, following an SEI. After this I receive a coded slice of an IDR picture followed by 29 P slices and then repeat the process. Doesn't seem to be out of sync either, as it does the same thing over and over.

After Playing back the video that's been captured, every 5 to 10 seconds give or take... the frames look like they jumble back a second or two and then go back to where they are suppose to be and then plays normal for about 5 to 10 seconds and does it again.

Here's some code:

```
var payloadOffset = packet.Payload.Offset;
var offset = payloadOffset + packet.HeaderOctets;
var count = packet.Payload.Count - (offset + packet.PaddingOctets);
var packetData = packet.Payload.Array;

if (count <= 2)
{
    return;
}

var firstByte = packetData[offset];
var nalUnitType = (byte)(firstByte & Binary.fiveBitMaxValue);

switch (nalUnitType)
{
    case NalUnitType.Unknown:
    case NalUnitType.PayloadContentScalabilityInformation:
    case NalUnitType.Reserved:
    {
        return;
    }
    case NalUnitType.FragmentationUnitA:
    {
        if (count > 2)
        {
            var fuHeader = packetData[++offset];
            var start = (fuHeader & 0x80) >> 7 > 0;

            ++offset;

            var fragmentSize = count - offset;

            if (start)
            {
                var nalHeader = (byte)((firstByte & 0xE0) | (fuHeader & Binary.fiveBitMaxValue));

                Buffer.Write(NalUnitType.StartCode, 0, 3);
                Buffer.WriteByte(nalHeader);
            }

            if (fragmentSize > 0)
            {
                Buffer.Write(packetData, offset, fragmentSize);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
    default:
    {
        // default becomes 1.

        if (nalUnitType == 6 || nalUnitType == 7 || nalUnitType == 8)
        {
            Buffer.WriteByte(0);
        }

        Buffer.Write(NalUnitType.StartCode, 0, 3);
        Buffer.Write(packetData, offset, count - offset);

        return;
    }
}
```

I take the buffer and then write it out to a h264 file, clear the buffer and receive more packets and the order of SPS, PPS, SEI, I slice, and P slice are consistent with what appears valid information.

Quality of the video looks good but it does this weird skipping thing.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, hoping someone can shed some light.

Cheers.

**EDIT**

Turns out I don't always get 29 P slice's. Looking into the frame number, sometimes when I get the 29th P slice the next packet is not an SPS but another P slice with a frame number of 20, and then counts up to 29 again and then I get my SPS.

It appears this is why the skipping occurs as there are too many P slices and haven't put together the packets yet. But why only every 10 seconds or so?